# To use a library using src code without installing it

Tags: c, build

I am trying to use a c library libpostal .But due to system restraints i cannot install the library.
I am able to set the data_dir using DLIBPOSTAL_DATA_DIR="/my/file/path".
This leads to the below error

```
    abhiram@abhiram-Lenovo-G50-70:~/libpostal-master/src$ gcc -DLIBPOSTAL_DATA_DIR='"$/home/abhiram/libpostal-master/data"' -o main  main.c libpostal.c file_utils.c string_utils.c json_encode.c -std=c99 -w
    In file included from sparse_matrix.h:46:0,
             from averaged_perceptron.h:27,
             from address_parser.h:52,
             from libpostal.c:10:
    matrix.h:9:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
    #include <config.h>
                      ^
    compilation terminated.
    file_utils.c:42:6: error: conflicting types for ‘is_relative_path’
    bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent) {
         ^
    In file included from file_utils.c:1:0:
    file_utils.h:59:6: note: previous declaration of ‘is_relative_path’ was here
    bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent);
         ^
    file_utils.c: In function ‘is_relative_path’:
     file_utils.c:43:22: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
 return strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0;
                  ^
     file_utils.c:43:55: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
 return strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0;
                                                   ^
```

I can only use the gcc compiler to run c code and also run python script i am trying to use the source code instead of the library.
I cant build the file or even run configure due to not having the permission at my target location i need to create a package which i can paste at a location and run directly without any other dependencies.

I am working on my on system curently where i have all permission but i need to create a package which will be used on a system by user without any access permissions and ./configure make cannot be used due to permission denied.

Comment: check the makefile for what it does

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the build commands or the `Makefile` you use to build the program that is supposed to use `libpostal`. You could install `libpostal` to a directory below your HOME directory and specify this as a library localtion (`-L library_dir)`. The build of `libpostal` seems to use a `configure` script. Run `configure --help` to see which settings you can modify. Maybe there is an option for `libpostal_data_dir` or its parent directory. There might be some options `--with-something` or `--enable-something` ...

Comment: Thanks @AnttiHaapala it got cleared in the makefile

Comment: @Bodo I have edited the question. My problem is i cant run configure at target location i need to run this directly without building anything at target location

Comment: but you can target your local directory!

Comment: @Abhiram You forgot to show the command line that prints the error messages. Are you trying to **build `libpostal`** or are you building a **program that uses `libpostal`**? What means "I can't run configure at target location"? What happens if you try it? How did you build libpostal or how did you get it onto your target system?

Comment: @bodo I have edited the post if i try to run configure it will just say access denied. I need to create a package on my system so that on target location all i need to use is gcc to execute the functionality of libpostal

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I  can run neither run configure nor make on the intended target system. Would it work if i create the .config file on my system and then add it to the files on target system ? How do i ensure no connections are created which target location on my system as those will be absent on target system

Comment: @Abhiram Please copy and paste to your question the exact command and error message when running `make` or `./configure` and the output of `ls -l ./configure`. What is your operating system? Please tell more details about your restriction. Why don't you have the necessary permissions? I assume you are running this on your own laptop because it shows `abhiram@abhiram-Lenovo-G50-70`.

Comment: @Bodo I need to run the package later on a server where i don't have access on trying to run any of the above commands i get  " cannot execute [Permission denied]" I have edited the post for my system details

Comment: In short, you should still build the library separately, then use that when building your program. You don't need to install it to use it, or you can install it under your home directory and use it from there, which ever seems easier. You could also build it as a static library, so you don't need to have the .so library file along with your executable binary.

Comment: Then build a static library on your build system and link your program with the static library. If you don't copy and paste the entered command with the error message and what you get asked for it is difficult to give useful answers. If you don't have the permission to execute a shell script `configure`, can you execute a binary program you copy to the target system?